# What is the exact syntactic ambiguity that requires parentheses around a yield expression in an OR assignment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, yield

The following code...
*Assume that the yield is inside a generator function and that `something` and `else` are defined, etc.*

```js
const value = something || yield else();
```

...produces the following in V8 (Chrome or Nodejs):

```
                const start = initial || yield wait();
                                         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
```

...and this in Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: yield is a reserved identifier
```

I first noticed this in a [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) [coroutine](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) I was writing. The fix is to wrap the `yield wait()` in a parentheses.

This error happens at parse time rather than at execution time; so, my first assumption is that this is because there's a syntactic ambiguity here. I looked at [the yield keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) which defines it as:

```
[rv] = yield [expression];
```

`yield` takes an expression and returns a value. This does *not* happen without the `||` (OR) operator as `const value = yield else();`; so, I looked at [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The `||` (OR) operator is evaluated at **5** before the `yield` operator at **2**. The precedence looks fine.

It looks like the `||` (OR) operator requires an expression on either side and while I assume that `yield [expression]` *is* an expression, perhaps that's not true? Why is it that I need to wrap that part in parentheses to make it *explicitly* an expression? What could `|| yield` be ambiguous with? I'm sure I'm just missing it; or, is there some sneaky/deeper reason for this?

This question was also notoriously difficult to search for, so hopefully I'm not duping here.

(You can use this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/rNidnFuyIOFkRkkcyWRV to make the error happen if you'd like to see it.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to figure out the syntax rules, you have to [look at the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/).

A [*LogicalOrExpression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-binary-logical-operators) is defined as

```
LogicalANDExpression:
  BitwiseORExpression
  LogicalANDExpression && BitwiseORExpression

LogicalORExpression:
  LogicalANDExpression
  LogicalORExpression || LogicalANDExpression
```

A *LogicalANDExpression* can only contain *BitwiseORExpression*s. But a *YieldExpression* is not a *BitwiseORExpression*, it's an [*AssignmentExpression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-assignment-operators):

```
AssignmentExpression:
  ConditionalExpression
  [+Yield] YieldExpression
  ArrowFunction
  LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression 
  LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperatorAssignmentExpression
```

It basically it is higher up in the expression hierarchy:

```
                 +--------------------------+                
                 |   AssignmentExpression   |                
                 +--------------------------+                
                               ^                             
                               |                             
              +----------------+---------------+             
              |                                |             
              |                                |             
+--------------------------+     +--------------------------+
|  ConditionalExpression   |     |     YieldExpression      |
+--------------------------+     +--------------------------+
              ^                                              
              |                                              
              |                                              
+--------------------------+                                 
|   LogicalORExpression    |                                 
+--------------------------+                                 
              ^                                              
              |                                              
              |                                              
+--------------------------+                                 
|   LogicalANDExpression   |                                 
+--------------------------+                                 
              ^                                              
              |                                              
              |                                              
+--------------------------+                                 
|   BitwiseORExpression    |                                 
+--------------------------+
```

---

A possibly explanation for *why* the syntax is structured this way is that `yield` is also a valid identifier name (outside of generators or yield expressions). But for more details you probably want to ask on https://esdiscuss.org/.

Comment: I read this question more as a question of _why_ `yield` is its own root expression.

Comment: Possibly. In that case, https://esdiscuss.org/ would be a better place to ask that question though.

Comment: It's a pretty tricky question to ask, not being a compiler/syntax aficionado, myself -- I don't know all the right terminology. If I change the `yield` to a `typeof` operator, for example (like `const start = initial || typeof initial;`), the parse phase passes. Apparently there's no ambiguity there, though `typeof` has a higher precedence than logical OR.

Comment: @Shibumi: If you look at the spec, `typeof` is a *unary operator*, which in the end is a *BitwiseORExpression*. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-unary-operators .

Comment: Yeah, you've probably got the right of it, then. Lots of things ultimately "being" _BitwiseORExpression_ isn't exactly intuitive though **:)**.

Comment: @Shibumi: I agree. It's often sufficient to only look at [*AssignmentExpression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-assignment-operators) to figure out what you can nest where. Not *that* many expressions accept an *AssignmentExpression*. Everything else is basically the same.